# .exe has stopped working when use thread module

Tags: nim-lang

I just copy the code from the example on [nim's offical documentation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/threads.html):

```
import std/locks

var
  thr: array[0..4, Thread[tuple[a,b: int]]]
  L: Lock

proc threadFunc(interval: tuple[a,b: int]) {.thread.} =
  for i in interval.a..interval.b:
    acquire(L) # lock stdout
    echo i
    release(L)

initLock(L)

for i in 0..high(thr):
  createThread(thr[i], threadFunc, (i*10, i*10+5))
joinThreads(thr)

deinitLock(L)
```

```bash
$ nimble build --threads:on
Verifying dependencies for thread@0.1.0
Building thread/thread.exe using c backend
$ .\thread
```

then thread.exe crashed...

```
 thread.exe 
   0.0.0.0 
   630c5e83 
   libwinpthread-1.dll 
   6.3.9600.20512 
   62cdfc6e 
   c0000135 
   00000000000ed1b0 
   1fc8 
   01d8bb71e28918ba 
   F:\MyProjects\Nim\thread\thread.exe 
   libwinpthread-1.dll 
   2044d161-2765-11ed-827a-6c86063c07b4
```

I have no ideas about it...Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way I'm a windows 8.1 user. I don't know if it take matters

Comment: Which version of nim are you using?

Comment: @cyraxjoe The latest version 1.6.6

Answer (score 0):

Gave it a try in Windows 8.1, it does fail.

Apparently is a [recent regression in nim](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/19713#issuecomment-1214481271) you can make it work if you compile it with `--threads:on --tlsEmulation:on` (or make sure mingw binaries is on your `PATH`).